# POST requests fail when <sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect" /> is set

Tags: .net, asp.net, http-status-code-302, cookieless, http-status-code-307

Consider the following case:

- A web server is running a .NET app with `<sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect" />`.
- A client is POSTing data to it using a simple `HttpWebRequest` (no cookies).

This seemingly simple case causes major failure.

Since .NET can't determine if the requesting agent (`HttpWebRequest`) supports cookies, it responds to the POST request with a 302 Found redirect to the same location with:

- a cookie named `AspxAutoDetectCookie` in the response
- a query parameter named `AspxAutoDetectCookie` in the forwarded location

The requesting agent is then supposed to request the new location, which `HttpWebRequest` does.  When .NET sees `AspxAutoDetectCookie` in the query string, it knows this is a re-request, and it can determine if cookies are supported by seeing if a cookie named `AspxAutoDetectCookie` is in the request headers.

The problem is that most requesting agents (web browsers, `HttpWebRequest`) treat a 302 Found as if it is a 303 See Other and make the re-request a GET, regardless of the original HTTP method! Any data sent in the initial POST request is not forwarded.

The correct response should be a 307 Temporary Redirect, which does not change the request method.  (A POST request to location X redirects to a **POST** request to location Y.)

Is there any way to change this behaviour in .NET so POST requests are not destroyed?

[Information on 3xx redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I can see to this is to append `AspxAutoDetectCookie=1` to all POST requests.

This way, ASP.NET will never redirect the request and we can dodge the 302 vs 307 question altogether.  If cookies are embedded in the request, ASP.NET will detect that cookies are supported, and if no cookies are embedded, it will assume they aren't.

Comment: It works if we append the header: `Cookie:AspxAutoDetectCookie=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any issues in using cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"? You may use it as a workaround solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use that setting. It has to work with "AutoDetect".

Answer (score 0):

I Know the thread is old but, another viable solution is to create and HTTP Module to fix http post over cookieless.

Here is one i use

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Specialized;
            using System.Web;
            using System.Web.SessionState;
            using System.IO;
            using System.Text;

            namespace CustomModule
            {
              public sealed class CookielessPostFixModule : IHttpModule
              {
                public void Init (HttpApplication application)
                {
                  application.EndRequest += new
                              EventHandler(this.Application_EndRequest);
                }
                private string ConstructPostRedirection(HttpRequest req,
                                                        HttpResponse res)
                {
                  StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
                  build.Append(
              "<html>\n<body>\n<form name='Redirect' method='post' action='");
                  build.Append(res.ApplyAppPathModifier(req.Url.PathAndQuery));
                  build.Append("' id='Redirect' >");
                  foreach (object obj in req.Form)
                  {
                    build.Append(string.Format(
              "\n<input type='hidden' name='{0}' value = '{1}'>",
                      (string)obj,req.Form[(string)obj]));
                  }
                  build.Append(
              "\n<noscript><h2>Object moved <input type='submit' value='here'></h2></noscript>");
                  build.Append(@"</form>"+
                  "<script language='javascript'>"+
                  "<!--"+
                  "document.Redirect.submit();"+
                  "// -->"+
                  "</script>");
                  build.Append("</body></html>");
                  return build.ToString();
                }
                private bool IsSessionAcquired
                {
                  get
                  {
                    return (HttpContext.Current.Items["AspCookielessSession"]!=null && 
                    HttpContext.Current.Items["AspCookielessSession"].ToString().Length>0);
                  }
                }
                private string ConstructPathAndQuery(string[] segments)
                {
                  StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder(); 

                  for (int i=0;i<segments.Length;i++)
                  {
                    if (!segments[i].StartsWith("(") 
                             && !segments[i].EndsWith(")"))
                      build.Append(segments[i]);
                  }
                  return build.ToString();
                }
                private bool IsCallingSelf(Uri referer,Uri newpage)
                {
                  if(referer==null || newpage==null)
                    return false;
                  string refpathandquery = ConstructPathAndQuery(
                                                    referer.Segments);
                  return refpathandquery == newpage.PathAndQuery;
                }
                private bool ShouldRedirect
                {
                  get
                  {
                    HttpRequest req = HttpContext.Current.Request;

                    return (!IsSessionAcquired
                                && req.RequestType.ToUpper() == "POST"
                      && !IsCallingSelf(req.UrlReferrer,req.Url));
                  }
                }
                private void Application_EndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
                {
                  HttpRequest req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
                  HttpResponse res = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                  if (!ShouldRedirect) return;
                  res.ClearContent();
                  res.ClearHeaders();
                  res.Output.Flush();
                  char[] chr = ConstructPostRedirection(req,res).ToCharArray();
                  res.Write(chr,0,chr.Length);
                }
                public void Dispose()
                {}
              }
            }
```